# BufferedWriter through command line not writing to file

Tags: java, file-io, command-line, bufferedwriter

So I'm trying to test my script as a programming puzzle and to test it I'm using the command line to point the std input and output to files in this way:

java -jar dist\PairwiseAndSum.jar < in.txt > out.txt

Here's the code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

try {
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    short a[] = new short[n];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextShort();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            sum += a[i] & a[j];
        }
    }

    bw.write(sum);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

The input file contains "5 1 2 3 4 5" and it's being loaded properly but there's no output on the out.txt file.
Now if I put "System.out.println(sum);" the result will actually be written in out.txt.
I saw simular posts here at SO but didn't manage to understand the issue :(.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
bw.write(sum);
```

That `write` method takes an `int` argument, but actually writes out a `char`.  So you are actually outputting the `sum` as a single Unicode code-point.  The Unicode code-point `15` is an non-printing ASCII control character, so when you view the output file, it *looks like* it is empty.

Change that line to this:

```
bw.write(Integer.toString(sum));
bw.newLine();
```